# Is there a way I can use Castle to inject dependencies into tests (MbUnit)?

Tags: testing, castle-windsor, mbunit

I've got unit tests written in C# using MbUnit & I have a bunch of helper classes that I use for constructing the test environment.  Is there a way to have MbUnit use Castle to resolve the test classes so I can inject dependencies in?

Comment: Why? What's your end goal? Or what are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm writing a functional test suite using MbUnit & Selenium & I have a bunch of helper & environment classes that I would like to have available to the test class.  Sure I could register them & just call `container.Resolve()` but I was hoping there would be a way I could put the dependencies into the constructor & they would be injected.  It's not a huge problem I'm solving, just trying to avoid a bunch of instantiation code really.